# Computing complexity of a function given recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

`T` describes the runtime of a program, and satisfies the recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = T(n/2 + sqrt(n)) + sqrt(6046)
```

What is the runtime complexity of the program that `T` describes?

Comment: Are you referring to runtime complexity? Looks like `O(n)`. `n/2 + sqrt(n) > log2(n)`, so it's larger than `O(log2(n))`. Meanwhile, `n/2 + sqrt(n) <= n` for `n >= 4`. So it's less than `O(n)` for most general cases making it a reasonable upper bound.

Comment: complexity of what? program that computes your recurrence ... or the recurrence describes runtime? First case is unanswerable without code for the latter its `O(n)` as biggest variable therm is `n/2` ... if the therms are describing something else we can only guess ...

Comment: This is not a program, then there is no runtime time complexity for this (at least give us information about it evaluation). Now, this could be a math equation for which you would like to know in which big-O the corresponding function lies, isn't it?

Comment: Commentators: it's clear enough what the person is asking, even though they describe the problem sloppily. (Sloppy language about complexity is also a bugbear of mine, so I sympathise with the snippy comments even as I disagree with their tone). I think it's better to edit the question to be more precise, since the question's intent is clear (which is what I did).

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, I replace `sqrt(6046)` by 1 for simplicity. Also I omit details about the terminating conditions for the recurrence.

`T` is defined by `T(n) = T(n/2 + sqrt(n)) + 1`.

For `n>16`, `sqrt(n) < n/4`, so `T(n) < T(n/2 + n/4) + 1` for `n>16`. Thus `T(n)` is `O(log n)`, since it's bounded above by `log_0.75(n)` where `log_0.75` is log base 3/4.

This is a tight complexity bound, since clearly `T(n) > log_2(n)`. That is `T(n) = Theta(log(n))`.